# Why slow compression with conducting walls should be isothermal?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, adiabatic, thermal-conduction

I know that for an isothermal process heat transfer is necessary so process should be slow and walls should be conducting for heat transfer to occur as a process cannot be isothermal and adiabatic at same time. But why slow compression of piston need to be isothermal, can't it be neither isothermal not adiabatic?
For example:

In figure,the walls of the container and the piston are weakly conducting. The initial pressure, volume and temperature of the gas are 200 KPa, 800 cm³ and 100 K resp. Find the pressure and the temperature of the gas if it is (a) slowly compressed (b) suddenly compressed to 200 cm³ (y = 1.5)

[image]

Why in part (a) we consider process as isothermal instead of neither isothermal not adiabatic?

Comment: You’re free to try to solve part (a) assuming an intermediate condition between isothermal and adiabatic, if you like. Is that problem solvable with the information you’re given? What do you think the question writer intended for you to do? When “slowly” is mentioned without an actual speed, what do you think is implied?

Comment: If that illustration is from a problem in a textbook, then it probably describes an [_idealized model_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealization_(philosophy_of_science)) of (some part of the cycle of) some [heat engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine).

Comment: When the word "slow" is used here, it *means* slow compared to the rate of heat transfer through the walls of the container: that is the implied context. Therefore, it *can't* be adiabatic, because heat transfer will necessarily happen, exactly because the process is "slow" compared to the rate of heat transfer.  If the process is slow "enough", it can be treated as an isothermal process (to a pretty good approximation, depending on the how slow it really is): that is the intent of the problem. It *seems* like you already get this, so I'm not sure what your question really is.

Comment: If the piston is moved rapidly, do you think that the temperature and pressure of the gas will be uniform during the charge?

Comment: Oh so word slow implies that it should be considered isothermal for solving otherwise it won't be solved.

Comment: @ChetMiller I don't think temperature and pressure would be uniform as it should be irreversible process

Comment: Now I realised that in part (b) it is irreversible adiabatic process so how can we apply P*V^y = constant for solving as it's derivation require ideal gas law to be applicable throughout the process and how can the pressure be well defined?

Comment: That is right.  So you have to calculate the work in an alternate way.

Comment: So Sir can you give some hints for the alternative way.

Comment: You control the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the piston by external means.  For example, for a massless-frictionless piston, the force per unit area of the gas on the piston must be equal to the external pressure on the piston.  Or, if the cylinder is vertical and the frictionless piston has mass, and, if, in the final state, the piston has come to rest, then the part of the work needed to raise the piston is equal to its weight times its upward displacement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152341/discussion-between-s-k-and-chet-miller).

Answer (score 2):

> But why slow compression of piston need to be isothermal, can't it be
> neither isothermal not adiabatic?

To be isothermal in the case of an ideal gas, the compression needs to be carried out slow enough that the energy transferring into the system by the compression work exactly equals the energy transferring out in the form of heat so that the temperature of the gas remains constant throughout the process.

The process can be neither isothermal nor adiabatic if the process is carried out not too quickly so that there is some heat transfer during the process.

Your last paragraph comes under the category of homework and exercise which we are asked not to answer.

Hope this helps.